# Protactor - Finding CSS Value (specifically in a body tag)

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have this tag in my app

```
<body id="ctl00_ctl00_Body" menuopen="true">
```

I'm trying expect if the menu is true or false. Right now I've tried

```
var body = element(by.id('ctl00_ctl00_Body'));
expect(body.getCssValue('menuopen').toEqual('true'))
```

and getting the error

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toEqual'
```

Thanks for any help! I am still very new at this. Google'd for the last few days and couldn't find anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bracket is misplaced in your code.

```
expect(body.getCssValue('menuopen')).toEqual('true')
```

From jasmine documentation:

> Expectations are built with the function expect which takes a value, called the actual. It is chained with a Matcher function, which takes the expected value.

In your case the matcher is `toEqual`

---

Answering the comment:

> Getting this error now UnknownError: unknown error: failed to parse
>   value of GET_EFFECTIVE_STYLE

`menuopen` is not a css value but an element attribute. So you have to use [`getAttribute`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#webdriverwebelementprototypegetattribute) instead of [`getCssValue`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#api-webdriver-webelement-prototype-getcssvalue)

```
expect(body.getAttribute('menuopen')).toEqual('true')
```

Comment: Getting this error now UnknownError: unknown error: failed to parse value of GET_EFFECTIVE_STYLE